# How to download .deb files in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, deb

I wanted to download a binary image file, specifically http://launchpadlibrarian.net/162108105/mingw-w64_3.1.0-1_all.deb. Currently, I can open it only using the Ubuntu software center. But that installs it to the system folder. But I want to download it to my own folder of choice and not to the system library.

Is there a command line instruction that can achieve that?

Please note that this particular deb file is very small, in kilobytes, but when it is downloaded using the Ubuntu software center, it will be in mega bytes. So, it is kind of an installer file. I want to download the binary images files that is pointed by the deb file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can open the url in your browser if you have a UI.

The command to download a file is wget.
In this case:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/162108105/mingw-w64_3.1.0-1_all.deb
```

Comment: @stijin: am afraid that's not what i want. I have clarified my question a bit. Please read above for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are saying the same file downloaded locally is smaller file I think that Software center actually requests something else even if states the specified url. This is why I think would be the best to sniff what exactly Software center downloads using tcpdump. See [here](http://blog.aplikacja.info/2013/04/use-tcpdump-to-sniff-http-requests/) and example how to do this while you are downloading it from the Software center.
Once you have the real url you can then download using wget or curl.

Comment: @vladmir: tx for the response! That might a good hack solution. But I thought the software center uses the deb file to run it as a "script" So, there could be downloads from multiple sources and other configurations involved. So, locating a single url might not work, just my quick thoughts.

Comment: In this case it is probably script within the deb file that does the rest of the download. You need to see what exactly does the script within the deb file by unarchiving it. Example how to do it here - http://www.g-loaded.eu/2008/01/28/how-to-extract-rpm-or-deb-packages/